# Send object from controller to another using service

Tags: angularjs

Hi getting Started with  AngularJs, and I need to send an object from controller to another for that I create a service, the problem is the value of the object (SessionUser) doesn't change, can you help me please with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6o1Ifw682GYiS9HpAD2Q?p=preview)

my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrls',function($scope,SessionUser) {
    $scope.verification=function(user){

        SessionUser.id=user.id;
        SessionUser.type=user.type;

        window.location.href = 'page2.html';  
    }
});

app.controller('ctrls2',function($scope,SessionUser) {

    console.log(SessionUser);
    $scope.obj=SessionUser;

});
```

the services:

```
app.service('SessionUser', function () {
    this.type = '';
    this.id = 0;
});
```

Comment: I think each creation of controllers, also creates a new instance of Service or whichever is injected in the controller.

Comment: First you need to create partial views of Angular than you need to pass data between your views

Answer (score 3):

You are conceptually right by using a `service` to share data between your controllers. A service gets only created once per Angular application and is a singleton.

But in your plunker example you created not one but two AngularJS applications. One for `index.html` and another application in `page2.html`. You created two instances of the same app. That is the reason why you cannot see the data in `page2.html`.

Every page refresh in an AngularJS app basically recreates your app and reinitializes your services. Thats also the reason why you often want to create a so called [Single Page Application](http://singlepageappbook.com/goal.html)

If yout want to have multiple pages (aka views) in your application in AngularJS you have to use the `routing` concept.
The official tutorial at step 7 [Routing & Multiple Views](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) explains it better than I could do it.

You have to configure your views/pages inside of angular with the `ngRoute`-module:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', {
      templateUrl: 'page1.html',
      controller: 'ctrls'
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'ctrls2'
    })
    .otherwise('/page1');
});
```

I [updated your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JR9ZSVbYnsoy9KWleL1Y?p=preview) and incorporated the `ngRoute` module.

Answer (score 1):

When you move to another page, you get a new instance of your service. If you want to send your data between pages, you should use routing like [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It has [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) functionality. You can do data sending via `$state` in routing config 
like this:

```
state('page2', {
            url: '/page2',
            templateUrl: 'page2.html' ,
            controller: 'Page2Controller',
            params: {
                type: null,
                id: null
            }
        });
```

And in your HTML:

```
<!--ui-sref do redirect to page2 state-->
<a class="button" ui-sref="page2({ type: type, id: id})">Valider!</a>
```

In your page2 controller:

```
page2.$inject = ['$stateParams'];

if ($stateParams.type !== null && $stateParams.id !== null) {
   //some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is my approach to set and get data from one place to antoher

Basically the headInfo array is filled with data (by SetData) and when you need it you can call the GetData function

```
.factory('CommonService', function () {
    var headInfo = [];
    return {
        SetData: function (key, data) {
            headInfo[key] = data;
        },
        GetData: function (key) {
            return headInfo[key];
        },
     }
});
```

In your first controller you do

```
CommonSevice.SetData('someName', someValue);
```

And in your 2nd Controller you do

```
CommonSevice.GetData('someName');
```

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I use factory to share data between different controllers. See my code below.

```
var app = angular.module('App', []).
    controller('Ctrl1', function($scope,NameFactory){
        console.log('Initial Name ',NameFactory.Get());
        NameFactory.Set('Uthaiah');
        console.log('After change ',NameFactory.Get());
    }).
    controller('Ctrl2',function($scope,NameFactory){
        console.log('Controller 2',NameFactory.Get());
    }).
    factory('NameFactory',function(){
        var Name = "Sanju";
        this.Get=function  () {
            return Name;
        }
        this.Set =function  (val) {
            Name = val;
        }
        return this;
    });
```